# How to calculate day of the week provided the year and the day?

Tags: python, datetime

For example if I input the year - 2012 and the day 72, it should return Tuesday.The following code will return proper day of the week, but requires month as an input. How could I do this without the month argument, since I am not requiring a user to type  in a month?

```
days = {0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday', 2:'Wednesday', 3:'Thursday', 4:'Friday', 5:'Saturday', 6:'Sunday'}

userdate = date(year, month, day)
weekday = userdate.weekday()

return days[weekday]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

startDate = datetime(your_year, 1, 1)
endDate = (startDate + timedelta(days=days_from_the_begining)).weekday()
```

E.g:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_weekday(year, dayOfTheYear):
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

    userWeekDay = (datetime(year, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=dayOfTheYear)).weekday()
    return days[userWeekDay]
```

Comment: Thank you I understand how to do it now.

Comment: It seems a bit awkward to use a dictionary when a list would do. I know you copied that bit from the question, but still...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that can be adapted to any language. The divides need to be integer, I'm using `//` to make sure this works in Python 3.

```
def day_of_week(year, day, one_based=false):
    days = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
    weekday = (year*365 + (year-1)//4 - (year-1)//100 + (year-1)//400 + day + (5 if one_based else 6)) % 7
    return days[weekday]

>>> day_of_week(2012, 72)
'Tuesday'
```

The odd part where it keeps dividing the year by different values accounts for the leap year rules. A year is a leap year when it is divisible by 4, except when it's divisible by 100 and *not* divisible by 400. Thus 2000 was a leap year but 1900 wasn't.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  Using this and entering (2014,60) for March 1, 2014 it says Sunday.  But it should be Saturday.

Comment: @slashdottir, it's not stated in the question but the day is zero-based. March 1 2014 is day 59, not 60.

Comment: I see.  convention has it at 60, but zero based makes sense too.  thank you

Comment: @slashdottir, I've made an edit to allow both 0-based and 1-based days to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime
weekday = datetime.strptime('%d %d' % (year, day_of_year), '%Y %j').weekday()
```